# fastapi field masks

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask, header

Есть ли в [fastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) (аналог flask) field-masks?

Вот пример из [flask-rest-plus API](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mask.html)

Comment: надо смотреть спецификацию старлет и пидантик. фастапи это всего-лишь обертка над ними..

Comment: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/868